# Is it the right usage of agreeable?"This model produces more agreeable results to experiments"

Tags: word-usage

I'm writing a paper, and in this paper I used a new model to predict a physical phenomenon. Now I want to express the predicted results is in better agreement with experiment than old model is. The whole sentence I want to write is "Bubble-based energy minimization multi-scale drag model considered mesoscale effect, which enhances the heterogeneous reaction between gas phase and solid phase, and produces more agreeable results to experiments experiments than the old one does."
If agreeable is not acceptable, could I say "...produces more consistent results with experiment."?

Comment: Have you looked up *agreeable* in a dictionary? It can mean, but doesn't always mean, *to be in agreement with*. The sentence in your title would seem to imply *in agreement with*, but I am not clear on what it is saying. Please could you provide more context.

Comment: In fact, I have looked it up in the dictionary and find no such usage. so I was wondering if it acceptable to say so. Or which other usage is better?

Comment: What is meant by *more agreeable results*? It could mean *results more pleasing to the experimenters*, *results on which parties were able to agree more readily*, or even *results which were more as expected*. Where does it come from and what is the overall context?

Comment: [M-W's](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agreeable) '**3** being in harmony :  consonant' would seem to license this. But this sense is unusual to very odd. //// Essentially, it's [your doing] the experiments that produce/s the results. But I agree that it is probably better to front 'This model'.  'This model predicts experimental results better than the old one does / did.' / / 'This model accords better with experimental results.' ('Accords' is less restricted in distribution here than 'agrees'; 'The predictions derived using this model agree better with exptl results.' is wordy.)

Comment: "More consistent with experiment" is a good way to say it, as user2428107 says in his/her answer.  Also "in better agreement with experiment" if fine, as user2428107 says.  "More agreeable"  - No.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "more consistent with experiment" in this case.

"Agreeable" suggests that the results are pleasing.

However "in agreement with" is fine.